# How do I get sound from my html5 web app to play in an android webframe?

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I'm trying to get my web-app ([hiit-fit-training.com](http://hiit-fit-training.com)) to run inside of an android web view. It works fines visually but has some issues with the sound. . Inside the web app I use a third party TTS service ([responsiveVoice](http://responsivevoice.org/)) and a simple beep:

`var audio = new Audio( '../assets/_sound/beep.mp3' );
 audio.play();`

The beep has never played in the web-app and the TTS voice worked occasionally in the baconreader android app web-view. They both work perfectly inside of android Chrome. Neither sound sources work in my web-view though..

Although most likely different, pointing the web-view at youtube, I discovered it can play youtubes audio.

Are there any workarounds or suggestions on how to implement my sound effects?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out by looking through the console and discovered a security setting:

`Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.`

It can be solved by using the following setting:

`myWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);`

Comment: I don't get this error, but It's worked very well. Thank you.